# How to insert empty date into postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a column that requires a timestamp with time zone but I cannot use a built in pgSQL function nor can I modify the column to accept null dates. How can I insert a string date in the right format manually that represents no time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no *empty* timestamp other than `null`, but you can use one of the special date/time values `infinity` or `-infinity`.

```
select 'infinity'::timestamp, '-infinity'::timestamp

 timestamp | timestamp 
-----------+-----------
 infinity  | -infinity
(1 row)
```

See [Table 8.13. Special Date/Time Inputs.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE)